# How to apply for loop for comma separated arguments passed to the script in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of folders listed below:

- C:\Program Files
- C:\temp
- C:\John Snow

I have to pass comma separated arguments to scripts like given below:

```
script.bat C:\Program Files,C:\temp,C:\John Snow
```

After passing to the script I need to filter out comma separated argument and apply for each loop and echo the argument value and execute dir command to list files in that director

Comment: you need to iterate arguments in the `script.bat` or you want to call script .bat with each of the items?

Comment: I need to iterate arguments in **script.bat** . And inside for loop, I need to execute DIR command for each arguments

Comment: You can pass the list of arguments surrounded by double quotes and access this list with %1 inside the script. From there you can iterate using a `for /f` command giving "," as delimiter. Check [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: @Danial Luz, If you could write it for me it will be better because I'm not that good in batch scripting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "_params=%*"
if not defined _params (
  echo %~nx0: nothing to do
  pause
  exit /B
)
set "_params=%_params:,=","%"
for %%G in ("%_params%") do (
  echo dir "%%~G"
)
```

**Output**

```
==> 37321331.bat
37321331.bat: nothing to do
Press any key to continue . . .

==> 37321331.bat C:\Program Files,C:\temp,C:\John Snow
dir "C:\Program Files"
dir "C:\temp"
dir "C:\John Snow"

==>
```

Above script requires some elaborating: it would fail if some argument is enclosed in a pair of double quotes:

```
==> 37321331.bat C:\Program Files,C:\temp,"C:\John Snow"
dir "C:\Program Files"
dir "C:\temp"
dir ""C:\John"
dir "Snow"""
```

**Edit**. Use next code snippet to fix it: `set "_params=%_params:"=%"` would remove all `"` double quotes from supplied string.

```
set "_params=%_params:"=%"
set "_params=%_params:,=","%"
for %%G in ("%_params%") do (
  echo dir "%%~G"
)
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%*` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: For Me its coming like this:        c:\batch>com.bat "c:\Program Files,c:\John Snow"
dir ""c:\Program"
dir "Files","c:\John"
dir "Snow"""

Comment: @ThejeshPR This behaviour I have admonished already: please read entire answer.

Comment: @ThejeshPR fixed for double quotes.  Please consider marking most helpful answer as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "args=%*"
set "args=%args:,=","%"
for %%# in ("%args%") do (
  dir "%%~#"
)
```

try this.

Comment: **%%#** value is coming NULL, its just listing current directory files.

Comment: Its coming Like this(i have use ech dir "%%~#"):   `c:\batch>com.bat "c:\Program Files,c:\John Snow"
dir ""c:\Program"
dir "Files","c:\John"
dir "Snow"""`   Its taking space as delimiter.

Comment: @ThejeshPR are you passing the line surrounded by double quotes?